# Magento 2 How to override Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book block in my custom module?

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account, address

I want to override block `Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book` in my custom module. And need to add a new function which returns module status enable/disable, which is defined in the model class. I need to call my custom function in **`book.phtml`** which is copied to my module.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already have the module created ?

Comment: yes i have already created module and copied "book.phtml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the below line in your custom modules `di.xml`

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book" type="<<Your Custom Modules Block File Path" />
```

And, in your custom modules block php file, override the desired method.

```
<?php

    namespace <<Custom Module Block Path>>;

    class CustomModuleBlockName extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book
    {
        public function <<methodname()
        {
            // Do your stuff here
        }
    }
```

Comment: can we override from layout xml file?

Comment: Along with the block changes, we may need to do layout xml occassionally. Share you layout xml file

Comment: i have below code in layout

customer_address_index.xml


<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Name\Module\Block\Rewrite\Address\Book" name="address_book" template="Name_Module::address/book.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceContainer>

Comment: with di.xml it gives error

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book

Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Name\Module\Block\Rewite\Address\Book\Modulestatus does not exist

Comment: Have you created the block ?

Comment: yes created block. with  name "Modulestatus"

Comment: Please update your post with all the related modules files and its contents.

Comment: error : 

Fatal error: Class 'Name\Module\Block\Rewrite\Address\Book\Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testing\app\code\Name\Module\Block\Rewrite\Address\Book\Modulestatus.php on line 5


code is : 

class Modulestatus extends Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy `Book.php` from `Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book` to `Vendor/ModuleName/Block/Address/Book` Add your custom function inside book.php.
2. In layout file, relate your template with the class file .

   ```
   <block class="Vendor/ModuleName/Block/Address/Book" name="customaddress" template="Vendor_ModuleName::your_layout_file.phtml"/>
   ```
3. Within template file, call your custom function. $block->yourFunction()

Answer (score 0):

I used layout xml to override phtml. i have blow code in my layout file for override.

We need to add all the dependencies in our module block file.

namespace Name\Module\Block\Rewrite\Address;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper;

class Book extends \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Book
{
    protected $currentCustomer;
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $addressRepository;
    protected $_addressConfig;
    protected $addressMapper;
    protected $_moduleStatusConfigProvider;

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer $currentCustomer,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig,
    Mapper $addressMapper,
    \Name\Module\Model\ModuleStatusConfigProvider $moduleStatusConfigProvider,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->currentCustomer = $currentCustomer;
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->_addressConfig = $addressConfig;        
    $this->addressMapper = $addressMapper;
    $this->_moduleStatusConfigProvider = $moduleStatusConfigProvider;
    parent::__construct($context, $customerRepository,$addressRepository,$currentCustomer,$addressConfig,$addressMapper,$data);        
}
```